# Typescript Intellisense with Web Forms and npm

Tags: visual-studio, npm, typescript-typings, intellisense

i'm using npm in my web forms project. Some of the modules come with typescript d.ts files or with an extra @types package. jQuery for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery.
Installing the @types/jquery package copies definition files in the node_modules@types\jquery folder and add the package to the package.json file.
But in my aspx file i have no instellisense for jQuery. I started typing "$(" but VS 2022 don't show intellisense help.

I added  `///<reference path=".\node_modules\@types\jquery\jquery.d.ts" />` at the beginning of the script block in my aspx page. Then it works. But i expect, that VS automatically detect the using of jQuery when i start typing.
Is this the normal behavior to add the `///<reference path="..." />` for every node module to every file to get intellisense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using 'web app - winform structure', the type of it is actually 'class library'.

In this situation, if you can't put the code in a place that emphasizes its type, then IntelliSense not appearing is entirely expected behavior.

It's like writing a python script directly in aspx. It's impossible for VS IntelliSense to recognize it directly. You have to put it in the 'script'.

By the way, if possible, please share related code and screenshots when you ask this type of question. :)